# Advanced DataGrid View filtering

Tags: vb.net

I have DataGridView with only 4 columns.
The first column is the product name
Second column discount
The third column is the price
The fourth column is the company name.

This data comes from compiling more than one excel file.  And I made that step
Required:

- Extracting the 3 biggest discounts per product, where the product name and price are similar with the same product and price for another company.
  -If there are only two discounts, they are automatically selected in case. IF there is one discounts, it is chosen directly.
  and Delete all data that do not apply to the conditions 1-2

simple  project with excel file

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AplhOhx2ceW8gRJa9ktsyFLMB0tK?e=m4iNE9

Image of the combined data

[image]

Another picture after reaching the Required

[image]

DataGrid View is filled by OleDbConnection
DataTable is the source of the data

The data comes from different Excel files and the simplified image has been placed above for an assembled file

my try code not work

```
 DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

       DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.
           AsEnumerable.
           GroupBy(Function(x) x(0)).
           SelectMany(Function(x) x.OrderBy(Function(y) y(1)).Take(3)).
           Skip(1).
           CopyToDataTable
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Whenever it is possible you should post text instead of images .

Comment: To have a sort of Distinct selection based on Product type and Discount value, you should GroupBy() using both (e.g., `.GroupBy(r => new { product = r["PROD-NAME"], price = r["DISCOUNT"] })`) and take the first. But then you have a problem there, because you don't know how many distinct discounts a Product can have, it may be the same discount for all (so you take just one product) thus even if you take the top 3 products after, you'll end up with just one, as it will happen for `PRODC`...

Comment: You have to know the grouping count, compare to the overall number of Products of a type (a second grouping), then decide how many to take from the two groupings you have generated. It's not complicated, but I don't think a one-liner is the best solution for this. Maybe create the first grouping with the two Columns values (Product and Discount), then use a standard loop for the evaluation and comparison.

Comment: HI Jimi First of all, I thank you for your help. Can the entire code be modified with the example in order to understand the modification mechanism